# Can't set disabled=false (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this function:

```
function disableDiv(divId, action){
    var divId = byId(divId);

    if(action==true){
    divId.style.display='none';
    }
    else if(action==false){
    divId.style.display='block';
    }

    var inputs = divId.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var selects = divId.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var i;

    for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].disabled=action;
        }

    for (i=0; i<selects.length; i++){
        selects[i].disabled=action;
        }
}
```

This takes a divId (id of DIV) and an action (false or true) and gets all inputs and selects inside the div, and sets their disabled attribute to either false or true.

According to Firebug, the elements inside the Div are disabled all the time. But they should be active once hitting a drop-list option... The triggering is fine so you know.
I can see this function beeing called by using alert boxes, and it does in fact set the disabled=false. But the elements are still disabled.

Something to point out is that according to firebug, the disabled attribute looks like this:

```
    <input name="test" id="test" disabled="">
```

Note there is just two doublequotes... Shouldn't it say "disabled='disabled'" or "disabled=true"?

Any tips on how to troubleshoot further?

Here is how I call the function:

```
(category=="Cars")?disableDiv("nav_sub_cars", false):disableDiv("nav_sub_cars", true);
```

If you need more input, just let me know...

Thanks

Comment: Time to move to jQuery. It's all the rage with the kids these days.

Comment: jQuery would be overkill just for this.

Comment: Make sure your action input is the boolean true or false and not the string "true" or "false", that could very well have been your problem.

Comment: jQuery, for this? Never.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Edited to reflect the comments.

According to the W3C the code you posted should be correct.  The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.  Use of the `removeAttribute()` method may be helpful as well.

In my experience, you can also achieve this effect using the string values 'disabled' or ''.  This may work because these values are coerced into a boolean representation when the browser encounters them.

Comment: ??? I have a similiar function which disables some inputs by hitting radio button. When hittin radio 1, all elements are disabled, but when hitting radio 2, all are enabled again. It works just fine. Care to explain that?

Comment: Different entities might perform in different ways, but the proper standard compliant HTML says that you should declare an element disabled as disabled="disabled"

Comment: Regarding the [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) and [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls) specs the `disabled` attribute is described  as a `boolean` attribute, where the presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

Comment: I think this refers to another answer I gave where I used true/false. The strange thing is using true/false worked fine in FF and IE6. But using "disabled" will indeed be better.

Comment: Kieranmaine: the string "disabled" is incorrect for the `disabled` property. It should be Boolean `true` or `false`. See CMS's comment.

Comment: Tom Gullen: either `disabled="disabled"` or just `disabled` are valid attributes for inputs in HTML.

Comment: All very interesting. Thanks Tim.

Comment: @Tim Down - I've revised the answer in a way that I believe reflects your comments.  Can you help explain why the code the user posted initially, which adheres to the W3C, does not work (the reason for the post)?

Comment: g.d.d.c: The code posted initially looks correct. There must be some other problem to do with the rest of the set-up that we haven't seen. There is a general issue that a lot of people seem confused about the relationship between attributes and properties, a confusion that I think is exacerbated by jQuery's `attr()` method, which in the majority of cases sets a property, not an attribute. In general, because of incorrect behaviour in IE and for simplicity, you're better off forgetting about attributes in JavaScript and just using properties.

Comment: I think you're (still) confusing the `disabled` HTML **attribute** and the `disabled` **property** you get/set in JavaScript using `element.disabled [= (true|false)]`. Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533732%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

try `.disabled = null` or `.removeAttribute('disabled')`. My understanding is that it's the presence or absence of the `disabled` attribute that governs disabledness, not its value.

Comment: Agreed. This also works:

$('#myButton').prop("disabled", null);

Answer (score 6):

To disable elements you need to use attribute `disabled = "disabled"` rather than `true` or `false`. To make it enabled again, you need to remove the `disabled` attribute. Modify your code like this:

```
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  if (action === false) {
    inputs[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
  else {
    inputs[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

for (i=0; i<selects.length; i++){
  if (action === false) {
    selects[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
  else {
    selects[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

The `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` functions are used to set and remove `disabled` attribute respectively.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: WAM: How is it useless? And what is the problem with `action === true/false`???

Comment: @ms2ger: You people are wasting my time. It is not never equivalent ! OP was setting `disabled` to true or false which was wrong. It can be set by `disabled="disabled"` or removing the `disabled` attribute something I am doing with `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`.

Comment: This code, while excessively verbose, is correct - while the 'correct' marked answer is not, so I'm not sure how it ended up with a -1.

Comment: Stuart: this answer may be correct according to the DOM standard (apart from the copy/paste error in the first section), but you're much better off using the `disabled` property instead.

Answer (score 3):

More code needed. Everything looks correct, and setting the `disabled` property of an `<input>` element to a Boolean value (the correct approach) certainly works in Firefox, regardless of the presence or absence of the `disabled` attribute in the source HTML.

Comment: +1. I don't understand why this answer was at the bottom, the other answers confuse the property with the attribute.