# Ember - Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: api, rest, laravel, ember.js, ember-data

### My application

Im trying to build a fairly simple application using Laravel as a RESTfull API server and Ember as my fontend framework

My backend server lives on `http://api.example.com/1.0/`

My frontend lives on `http://www.example.com/`

Ive just started this project so I'm only a few hours into the devlopment, so there might be some configuration issues that Im missing here, but anyway.

Im trying to get a list of products from my server and display them in my ember application using ember-data

Im running ember 2.0.2 and ember-data 2.0.0

Im getting the following error in chrome.

### Error

> Error while processing route: product Cannot read property 'replace'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>       at Object.func (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:45832:15)
>       at Object.Cache.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:23421:36)
>       at decamelize (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:45874:29)
>       at Object.func (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:45789:12)
>       at Object.Cache.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:23421:36)
>       at Object.dasherize (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:45878:35)
>       at ember$data$lib$system$normalize$model$name$$normalizeModelName (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:66295:27)
>       at ember$data$lib$serializers$json$serializer$$default.extend.modelNameFromPayloadKey
>   (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:75184:67)
>       at ember$data$lib$serializers$json$serializer$$default.extend._normalizeResourceHelper
>   (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:75064:30)
>       at Array.map (native)

### Files

In ember I have generated a product resource giving my the following files.

```js
// app/routes/product.js

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('product');
  }
});
```

```js
// app/model/product.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  price: DS.attr()
});
```

### JSON response

The Json returned from my api `http://api.example.com/1.0/products`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "dolores",
      "price": "59015",
      "created_at": "2015-09-06 16:18:13",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-06 16:18:13"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "debitis",
      "price": "57449",
      "created_at": "2015-04-07 14:45:16",
      "updated_at": "2015-04-07 14:45:16"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is adapter/serializer error, it's not descriptive though. Payload is wrong for the JSONAPIAdapter (the default adapter)

You should modify payload as:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "products",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "dolores",
      "price": "59015",
      "created-at": "2015-09-06 16:18:13",
      "updated-at": "2015-09-06 16:18:13"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "products",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "debitis",
      "price": "57449",
      "created-at": "2015-04-07 14:45:16",
      "updated-at": "2015-04-07 14:45:16"
    }
  }]
}
```

or use RESTAdapter/Serializer with a such payload:

```
 {
  "products": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "dolores",
    "price": "59015",
    "created_at": "2015-09-06 16:18:13",
    "updated_at": "2015-09-06 16:18:13"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "debitis",
    "price": "57449",
    "created_at": "2015-04-07 14:45:16",
    "updated_at": "2015-04-07 14:45:16"
  }]
}
```

If you can't change response payload, you have to customize Adapter/Serializer pair. Check related questions on SO.

Links for details:

- [Guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_json-api-document)
- [JSONAPISerializer payload example](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html)
- [RESTSerializer payload example](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html)

Comment: Thank you, have been reading the ember docks, but I tend to easily get confused, so I totally missed that the type and attributes parameters weren't just values of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me.

**Version details:**

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.debug.js:DEBUG: Ember      : 1.11.0
ember.debug.js:DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.14.1
ember.debug.js:DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

**Cause of the issue:**

It seems that adding attributes to Handlebars elements using inline `if` helpers **also** causes the issue (whether the property that you are using on your condition is `true`, `false`, `null` or `undefined`).

*my-component.hbs*

```
<button class="btn btn-solve-my-problems" {{action 'solveIt}} {{if isNotSolvable 'disabled'}}>
  Solve my problems!
</button>
```

*my-component.coffee*

```
isNotSolveble: (->
  if @get('somethingMeaningful') then true else null
).property('somethingMeaningful')
```

**The solution:**

Instead of using the inline `if` helper, I am just attributing the value of `isNotSolvable` to the `disabled` attribute (nothing was changed on the `my-component.coffee` file).

*my-component.hbs*

```
<button class="btn btn-solve-my-problems" {{action 'solveIt}} disabled="{{isNotSolvable}}">
  Solve my problems!
</button>
```

PS.: the `null` being returned from the method has to do with the manipulation of the `disabled` attribute. It has nothing to do with the issue reported on this thread. It only reflects my scenario and how I've solved the issue. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557315).